# Checking size of matrix results in error

Tags: matlab, matrix

Error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Hi I am doing image conversion and I get an error when checking the size of the matrix. I am confused as to why I am getting it for this particular instance with the code:

```
size(maleGrey)
```

Here is the code I am running:

```
male = getAllFiles('male');

% Variable Initialization
size = 250*250;
numM = length(male);
maleGrey = zeros(size,numM);

% Convert to gray scale
for i = 1:numM
   rgb = imread(char(male(i)));
   img = single(rgb2gray(rgb));
   vec = img(:); % make it a vector of (62500,1) in size
   maleGrey(:,i) = vec; 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the mistake of using `size` as a variable when calling `size=250*250`. Once you do that in a workspace, the function is masked (overloaded) by the variable, and Matlab will always treat further calls to `size` as manipulations of the variable.

Call `clear size`, and the function will work as intended. Also, do not use `size` as name for a variable (or other function names like `length` or `double`, or `zeros` etc), but e.g. `siz`, or `numberOfRows` (because that's what your variable stands for).

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting (locally) Matlabs native function reference `size` by a variable name

```
% Variable Initialization
size = 250*250; % <--
```

Hence when you call `size(maleGrey)` it treats `maleGrey` as an index in the variable `size`.